# What's the standard font called that comes on droid x running 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-x, fonts

What font ships with the droid x on 2.3? Is the same font used across all android devices running 2.3?

Comment: The answer to this question applies to all phones that don't have a replaced standard font (like maybe some of the expensive fashion branded phones)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to Android 4.0 (aka Ice Cream Sandwich) It's called "Droid", and comes in Serif (Regular, Bold, Italic, Bold Italic), Sans (Regular, Bold), and Sans Mono variants.

A new font family "Roboto" was released with 4.0.

[Wikipedia article on Droid (font)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_%28font%29)

[Google+ post on Roboto](https://plus.google.com/114892667463719782631/posts)